# image matrix to input feature vector vector

Tags: numpy, matrix

this code converts a 2-dimensional matrix to a vector that contains all the values of the matrix, however, I don't understand what does this means :

### **image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1] * image.shape[2],1)**

I've searched in other forums such as the deeplearning.ai forum about what this line of code mean ... but it's as if nobody had the same doubt as me...

"""

## GRADED FUNCTION: image2vector

def image2vector(image):

```
Argument:
image -- a numpy array of shape (length, height, depth)

Returns:
v -- a vector of shape (length*height*depth, 1)



return image.reshape(image.shape[0]*image.shape[1]*image.shape[2],1) # WHAT DOES THIS MEAN??
```

"""

[image: I'm sorry for using an image but I've tried everything and I can't get stack overflow to let me post the code.]
**I'm sorry for using an image but I've tried everything and I can't get stack overflow to let me post the code.**

I sincerely don't understand anything about why **image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1] * image.shape[2],1)** may convert the matrix to a vector.

thank you for the explanation

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image` has the shape in the form of (H, W, C) which stands for H:height, W:width and C:channel. For example, an RGB image of size 256x256 has the shape of (256, 256, 3) and it contains 256*256*3 number of elements in total.

Same amount of elements can be stored in a vector with shape (256*256*3, 1). This is what `numpy.reshape` does. Shape of the final array should have the same number of elements in it with the input array.

Comment: ah wait, but... and then what it means the [0] ,[1] ,[2] of image.reshape(image.shape[0]*image.shape[1]*image.shape[2],1). ??? It means 0 of H , 1 of W and 2 of channel right?